# Parsing matrix data with Scala

Tags: arrays, parsing, scala, matrix

I have a log file with the following format:

```
3
1 2 3
1 2 3 
1 2 3
1 2 3
4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

The single number states the width of the matrix, as they always have the same height. And there can be several matrixes within the same log file. I wan't to parse the matrix data into an array. I read the lines with `scala.io.Source.fromFile(f).getLines.mkString`, but I'm struggling to fill the array.

```
for(i <- 0 to 3) {
    for(j <- 0 to N-1) {
        matrix(i)(j) = ...
    }
}
```

If the lines would have been indexed the same way as I want the matrix to be, this wouldn't be so hard. But when the lines(n) contains whitespace, newlines.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Btw, why not `fromFile(f).mkString` instead of `fromFile(f).getLines.mkString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this quite easily in a few simple steps:

1. First break the input into a `List` of lines
2. Then break each line into a `List` of `String`s
3. Then convert each `String` in the list to an `Int`
4. And finally summarize this `List` of `List`s of `List`s to a `List` of `Array`s (using a simple state machine)

The state machine is quite simple.

1. It first reads the number of lines in the next matrix and memorizes it
2. It then reads in that number of lines to the current matrix
3. After it has read the memorized number of lines it adds the current matrix to the list of read matrixes and goes back to step 1

The code will look something like this:

```
    import io.Source

    def input = Source.fromString(
       """|3
          |1 2 1
          |1 2 2 
          |1 2 3
          |4
          |1 2 3 1
          |1 2 3 2
          |1 2 3 3
          |1 2 3 4""".stripMargin) // You would probably use Source.fromFile(...)

    type Matrix = List[Array[Int]]

    sealed trait Command
    case object ReadLength extends Command
    case class ReadLines(i: Int, matrix: Matrix) extends Command

    case class State(c: Command, l: List[Matrix])

    val parsedMatrixes = input.getLines().map(_.split(" ")).map(_.map(_.toInt)).foldLeft(State(ReadLength, List())) {
       case (State(ReadLength, matrixes), line) => State(ReadLines(line(0), List()), matrixes)
       case (State(ReadLines(1, currentMatrix), matrixes), line) => State(ReadLength,((line::currentMatrix).reverse)::matrixes)
       case (State(ReadLines(i, currentMatrix), matrixes), line) => State(ReadLines(i - 1, line::currentMatrix), matrixes)
    }.l.reverse
```

And gives you the following result:

```
parsedMatrixes: List[Matrix] = 
List(
  List(Array(1, 2, 1), 
       Array(1, 2, 2), 
       Array(1, 2, 3)), 
  List(Array(1, 2, 3, 1), 
       Array(1, 2, 3, 2), 
       Array(1, 2, 3, 3), 
       Array(1, 2, 3, 4)))
```

Please be aware that this cannot be the final solution because it does not have any error handling. And it does not free up its resources (closing the source).

Comment: Wow. Really wish I knew Scala a bit better. Thanks so much! =)

Comment: How can I use stripMargin() when using Source.fromFile(...)? It seems dependent on using that to work properly.

Comment: stripMargin is only a trick to put multi line strings into a Scala file. When working with files, you might use def input=Source.fromFile("path/to/file") or something similar.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `scala.io.Source.fromFile(file)`, but it doesn't work as it does with your `fromString()`. Any idea why? When I try to access the second matrix array, I get an error.

Comment: Hm, I just reran the code with def input=Source.fromFile("""C:\Users\sschwets\Desktop\_tmp\matrix.txt""") and it worked without problems. I got exactly the same result as in the example above. The type of input is scala.io.BufferedSource with the file. This might be the first thing to check.

Comment: What do you mean with scala.io.BufferedSource? Isn't def lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file) sufficient enough?

Comment: I run the commands line by line in the Scala console. For each intermediate result it shows me the type of that result (the real type of the result, not the perhaps more generic type the Scala compiler gets through type inference). The def defines a function that will return a fresh data source each time it is called. And the Scala console gives me the type of that function. In the version with the String, the type of the function is scala.io.Source. In the version with the file, the type is scala.io.BufferedSource. It would be interesting, what type you get.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the file type is java.io.File.

Comment: OK, then you have the source for the problem. The type of input must be a subtype of io.Source. Perhaps you have some typo in there.

Comment: Ah, I found the bug. As you may have noticed I wrote that every matrix always have the same height (4). So for the first matrix, 3 states how many columns. But it's always 4 rows. Would that be difficult to change in your code? Really appreciated.

Comment: That is quite easy. Just change the line(0) to the number of rows. In your case: remove line(0) and insert 4.

Comment: Does the solution really have to be as complex as to even use a state machine?

Comment: Also, I would note that using a loop with simple `var`s instead of a `foldLeft` with immutable state types *might* be more practical; see Martin Odersky's "Scala with Style" @ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkTFx3-duc8 for why it's not always a good idea to stick to purely functional constructs, or, conversely, why it might often be a good idea to use mutable/imperative idioms such as state, locally, for either performance or readability, or both.

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke: It works great now, but somehow it can't parse matrices bigger then 4 in width. Any idea why? =)

Comment: @ErikAllik: Thanks for the link. You are right: one could of course do it with mutable variables. Might be easier in this case. I am currently freshing up my Haskell, so I might tend too much in the pure direction.

Comment: @timmyc31: How should it know, how many lines the matrix has? Is it safe to assume, that each line with only one element is a number of columns and each line with more elements is a row in a matrix? Or are there matrices with only one column, but multiple lines (column vectors)?

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke: yeah, I could indeed sense a certain amount of engineering just for the sake of engineering :) (no offense)

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke: Yes, that is safe to assume! Every matrix has always 4 rows, and the line with only one element idicates how many columns (min. 3 and max. 9 columns). Thanks again.

Comment: @stefan.schwetschke: Is it still possible that you could help me with that hopefully minior change?

Comment: Try the version in the other answer I have provided. But all the version work with bigger matrices, (more rows AND more columns) -- I have tried it. Perhaps you have to clean your input a little bit (trailing spaces, empty lines, etc.). If you have an example matrix that odes not work, just post it and I will try it :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the state machine is not needed; the following will give you a data structure equivalent in shape and content to the state machine solution:

```
import scala.io.Source

val input = Source.fromString(
  """|3
     |1 2 1
     |1 2 2
     |1 2 3
     |3 2 1
     |4
     |1 2 3 1
     |1 2 3 2
     |1 2 3 3
     |1 2 3 4""".stripMargin)

val matrices = input.getLines.grouped(5).map {
  case List(w, l1, l2, l3, l4) =>
    // feel free to use the value of `w.toInt` to do an assertion on the 4 lines
    List(l1, l2, l3, l4) map { _.split(' ').map(_.toInt).toList }
}

for (matrix <- matrices)
  println(matrix.map(_.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("\n"))

// prints:
// [1, 2, 1]
// [1, 2, 2]
// [1, 2, 3]
// [3, 2, 1]
// [1, 2, 3, 1]
// [1, 2, 3, 2]
// [1, 2, 3, 3]
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Nice, your code is quite short. But you can make it even shorter. val matrices = input.getLines.grouped(5).map(_.tail.map(_.split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList))

Comment: Yes; however, I'd argue the shorter version would 1) (arguably) be less readable and 2) would not allow the capture of the matrix width value in case it's needed for input validation.

Comment: The state machine is needed when parsing matrices with different numbers of rows. If it is guaranteed that each matrix has the same number of rows, then no state machine is needed.

Answer (score 0):

stefan's code is a great example of a functional state machine but I personally would prefer something like this

```
import io.Source

val input = Source.fromString(
   """|3
      |1 2 1
      |1 2 2
      |1 2 3
      |1 2 4
      |4
      |1 2 3 1
      |1 2 3 2
      |1 2 3 3
      |1 2 3 4""".stripMargin)

type Matrix = List[List[Int]]

def readMatrix(list: List[Int], height: Int, width: Int): Matrix =  {
  list.take(height * width).grouped(width).toList
}

def readMatrices(list: List[Int]): List[Matrix] = {
  if (list.isEmpty) List()
  else readMatrix(list.tail, 4, list.head) :: readMatrices(list.drop(4 * list.head + 1))
}

def printMatrix(matrix: Matrix) = println(matrix.map(_.mkString("", ", ", "")).mkString("", "\n", "\n"))

val parsedMatrices = readMatrices(input.mkString.split("\\s+").map(_.toInt).toList)
parsedMatrices.foreach(printMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following recursive solution?

```
val fixedHeight = 4

def readMatrices(lines: List[String]): List[Array[Array[Int]]] = {

  def readMatrices0(lines: List[String], result: ListBuffer[Array[Array[Int]]]): List[Array[Array[Int]]] = lines match {
    case None => result.toList
    case head :: tail =>
      val n = head.toInt 
      val mat = readMatrix(tail.take(fixedHeight))
      // check that the matrix has width n:
      require(mat.forall(_.length == n), "Incorrect width")
      readMatrices0(tail.drop(fixedHeight), result + mat)
  }

  def readMatrix(lines: List[String]): Array[Array[Int]] = 
    lines.map(_.split(' ').map(_.toInt).toArray

  readMatrices0(lines, new ListBuffer)
}

val mats = readMatrices(scala.io.Source.fromFile(f).getLines)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have a nice one:

- It deals with matrices with different number of rows (I bet there are matrices with different row numbers in the posters log files :-)
- It does not parse the whole input at once, but step by step (and uses hence not that much memory)
- It allows validation of the input

### Preparation

The first part is nearly the same as with my first answer. But I added `zipWithIndex` to preserve the line numbers of the input.

```
    import io.Source

    def rawInput = Source.fromString(
       """|3
          |1 2 1
          |1 2 2 
          |1 2 3
          |4
          |1 2 3 1
          |1 2 3 2
          |1 2 3 3
          |1 2 3 4""".stripMargin) // You would probably use Source.fromFile(...)

    type Matrix = List[Array[Int]]

    def parsedInput = rawInput.getLines().map(_.split(" ")).map(_.map(_.toInt)).zipWithIndex
```

### Version with Iterator

This version uses a classical Java iterator with mutable state. It is not in functional style, but should run quite fast:

```
    def matrixIterator= new Iterator[Matrix] {
      val input = parsedInput

      var expectedNumerOfRows : Option[Int] = None

      override def hasNext = input.hasNext

      override def next() : Matrix = {
        import collection.mutable.MutableList
        var matrix : MutableList[Array[Int]] = MutableList()
        while (input.hasNext) {
          val (currentLine, lineNumber)=input.next()
          if (currentLine.size==1){
            expectedNumerOfRows=Some(currentLine.head)
            return matrix.toList
          }else{
            matrix+=currentLine
            expectedNumerOfRows.filter(_ != currentLine.size).foreach{ expected : Int =>
              //println(String.format("Warning in line %s: Expected %s columns, got %s", lineNumber+1, expected, currentLine.size))
            }
          }
        }
        return matrix.toList
      }
    }.next()
```

### Version with Stream

This version uses Scala streams.It is recursive (although not tail recursive) and does not use mutable variables. It should be a little bit slower than the Iterator version, but is much more readable:

```
    def matrixStream : Stream[Matrix] = {
      def matrix(input : Iterator[(Array[Int], Int)], numberOfColumns : Int, currentMatrix : Matrix) : Stream[Matrix] = {
        if (!input.hasNext) {
          currentMatrix #:: Stream.empty
        }else{
          val (line, number) = input.next()
          if (line.size == 1) {
            currentMatrix.reverse #:: matrix(input, line.head, List.empty)
          }else{
            //if (numberOfColumns != line.size) println(...)
            matrix(input, numberOfColumns, line :: currentMatrix)
          }
        }
      }
      matrix(parsedInput,0,List()).drop(1)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions can help.

```
val space = " ".r
val arrayOfNumbersAsStrings = space.split(line)
val arrayOfNumbersAsInts = arrayOfNumbersAsStrings.map(_.toInt)
```

**UPD**

```
val arrayOfNumbersAsStrings = space.split(' ')
val arrayOfNumbersAsInts = arrayOfNumbersAsStrings.map(_.toInt)
```

Comment: This just exemplifies how to `spilt` a line and convert the resulting items to `Int`s. It does not however attempt to solve the problem of the OP. Also, `line.split(" ")` will do the job—regular expressions are not needed at all here.

Comment: Don't you know that `line.split(" ")` uses regular expression? And it recompiles the pattern `" "` every time.

However, if you suggest to use `line.split(' ')` then yes, that would be much faster.

Comment: OK, `line.split(' ')` then—my point was that mentioning regexps in a simple case like this seems like an overkill :)

Comment: Well, creating a state machine just for reading a couple of ints ... Regular expressions is a powerful tool for any sort of parsing. If @timmyc31 had slightly different format he would easily parse it with RegEx'es.

Answer (score -1):

Even without regular expressions:

```
for (i <- 0 to 3) {
  matrix(i) = line.split(" ")
}
```

Comment: But then I only get the first 4 numbers, it doesn't iterate over the entire line. And it also has some problems with newlines... :-/ `for(i <- 0 to 3) { puzzle.clues(i) = lines.split(" ").map(_.toInt); }` results in every row like "1231"